# reducing nodejs memory usage

Tags: node.js, memory

I'm using multiple nodejs instance. They are running some (different) simple scripts.
`top` say each of the instance use about 50-70MB reserved memory. (most of the used memory comes from node itself, only some MB comes from the running script)

This gives some memory usage like:

```
8 Instances x (50MB NodejsBase + 10MB AppSpecific) => 480MB
```

What would be nice:

```
8 Instances x 10MB AppSpecific + 1 x 50MB NodejsBase => 130MB
```

Is it possible to reduce the memory usage of the nodejs, when using multiple instance? Something like using a shared library of node for all the instance?